# R - Is there a simple way to convert all prefixes of day of week to number in a data frame column?

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime

Given the following dataframe generated by the code:

```
> df = data.frame(day=c('Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'),
+                 value=c(2,4,1,2,3,4,1))
> df
    day value
1   Mon     2
2  Tues     4
3   Wed     1
4 Thurs     2
5   Fri     3
6   Sat     4
7   Sun     1
```

I want to convert `Mon`, ... , `Sun` to `1`, ...`7` respectively to reflect the indexing of the day of the week.

Is there an easier/more straightforward way of doing this instead of using a defined function that checks the column value and converts the prefix to its assigned value?

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33008615/converting-day-of-week-to-number-in-r

Answer (score 1):

Define the days in the order you want and then use `match`

```
wdays <- c("Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun")
match(df$day, wdays)
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a pretty neat answer :)